# iOS UIImagePickerController vs AV foundation: looking to implement image capture with overlay, which is best?

Tags: ios, xcode, camera

I'm looking to build functionality into an iOS app that allows the user to take a picture or grab one from their library, apply an overlay to the image, then save the image with the overlay. There seems to be two ways to do image capture, using UIImagePickerController or AV foundation.

From what I've read UIImagePickerController seems to be easy to implement but allows for less customizability. Is this something I should use to do this? Or should I be looking into AV Foundation? New to this and looking for some tips or any links to tutorials that may help. Thanks!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

UIImage picker is much more simpler, but will give you less options. AV Foundation is more complex by my experience, I have been on a similar situation like you for the past 2 weeks and have experiminted with both. For overlay, I feel UIImage picker is easy since you can just override the Void CGrect method and get it done, However for complex things like cropping or capturing a part of the image clicker, AVfoundation works better. Best Wishes!!